# install packages (for python/django) from a txt file in ubuntu that was meant for windows

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, python, django

i am new but also have a weird problem. i m not deep into programming and i m just a power user, but i have to fix a typo in a python app which would be no problem but to run it again i have to get all the add-on and tools my predecessor added - and that on that specific version!
so i have a requirement.txt with fmany line for example

Django==1.8.4

dj-database-url==0.5.0

django-appconf==1.0.1

django-autocomplete-light==2.2.6

how do i adjust it that i can use that list for pip under ubuntu or is that not possible?

it worked fine in windows, it finds almost everythign (except django-mailgun) but ofc he has another requirement (foreman) that is not available under windows so i m not in a virtual enviroment in ubuntu trying to edit the list or trying to find the add-ons one by one (since those are 20 i need alot of time)

does anyone have an idea how to edit the txt to use it with ubuntu and pip?

(edit the exaple showed as 1 row but it is 4 rows)

Comment: Read `man dos2unix`.

Comment: Doesn't `pip install -r Requirements.txt` work? What error messages do you get?

Comment: sorry for late answer. so if i start pip install -r Requirements.txt it start just like in windows with the remark that python 2.7 has reached the end of its like and so on

but then it stops and says "no matching distribution found for django==1.8.4 

i assume it is because the txt is made or windows and the way the requirments are listed is for windows i played around alil with other txt files but not sure how to put the version so it can find something

Comment: Hi, yes pip install -r Requirements.txt did not work, but because there was a package in the requirements.txt that was outdated and not available anymore, i installed every single add-on by hand aand managed to single out proper order and which ones are not working anymore (for some reason mysql-python and pylibmc==1.2.3)

Answer (score 0):

The Python dependencies list file (by convention named "`requirements.txt`") by itself is probably not the problem here; it's a simple file that should work cross-platform without issue.

The main problem is probably the fact that Python packages themselves are not guaranteed to work cross-platform. You mentioned in a comment that one of the dependencies throwing an error is `pylibmc`: I tried `pip install`-ing that on Windows 11, and it failed because it requires a build tool not installed on my system. On Ubuntu 22.04 in WSL2, however, it installed fine without error.

Also from a comment:

> there was a package in the requirements.txt that was outdated and not available anymore

This is strange because PyPI (the repository where `pip` gets its packages) keeps old versions of packages indefinitely, precisely so that future installations will not fail simply due to having outdated requirements. You should share error messages to help us here in diagnosing your issue precisely.